# configure the oracle rest data service ORDS using JDK 7u-60?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-apex, java-7, oracle-ords

I've tried to install and configure the oracle data rest service using JDK 7 and I got the error bellow:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin>java -jar c:\conf\ords.war
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/dbtool
s/jarcl/Entrypoint : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

If anyone has the answer please write it down in the comment and thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of ORDS are you using.  The latest version does not support java 7 - "Oracle REST Data Services requires Java 8 or later. Java 7 is no longer supported. Please consult the documentation for the minimum supported Application Server versions for ORDS."

Answer (score 1):

There's no configuring for Java 7.

You must use Java 8.

We're going to be moving up to minimum Java 11 in early 2021, although it should work now